# SQL - FIlter out field names

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, psql

Is there a way to get only the value from the Select Query and not the field name?

Ex:

```
db=> select url from file where owner='abc' AND name='xyz';

                           url                           
---------------------------------------------------------
 /abc/xyz.com

(1 row)
```

I just need '/abc/xyz.com' and not url and (1 row)

Is there a filter I can use in the Select command itself?
if not, could you please suggest me other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) interactive mode, you can switch to "tuples-only" mode with the meta-command `\t`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

> `\t`
>
> Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count
> footer. This command is equivalent to `\pset tuples_only` and is
> provided for convenience.

The same is available as option `-t` for non-interactive mode. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#R1-APP-PSQL-3)

> `-t`   `--tuples-only`
>
> Turn off printing of column names and result row count footers, etc.
> This is equivalent to `\t` or `\pset tuples_only`.